# Passing Data Using Props to Display Polylines with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-props, polyline

Here is the reactjs code for displaying the movement of a vehicle on google map.
In the code, for the **path** array, latitude and longitude coordinates are assigned as hard-code values.
What I need is, how should pass latitude and longitude coordinates to "**path**" array from another component using props.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
  GoogleMap,
  Polyline,
  Marker,
} from "react-google-maps";

class Map extends React.Component {
  state = {
    progress: [],
  };

  path = [
    { lat: 18.558908, lng: -68.389916 },
    { lat: 18.558853, lng: -68.389922 },
    { lat: 18.558375, lng: -68.389729 },
    { lat: 18.558032, lng: -68.389182 },
    { lat: 18.55805, lng: -68.388613 },
    { lat: 18.558256, lng: -68.388213 },
    { lat: 18.558744, lng: -68.387929 },
  ];

  velocity = 5;
  initialDate = new Date();

  getDistance = () => {
    // seconds between when the component loaded and now
    const differentInTime = (new Date() - this.initialDate) / 1000; // pass to seconds
    return differentInTime * this.velocity; // d = v*t -- thanks Newton!
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.interval = window.setInterval(this.moveObject, 1000);
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    window.clearInterval(this.interval);
  };

  moveObject = () => {
    const distance = this.getDistance();
    if (!distance) {
      return;
    }

    let progress = this.path.filter(
      (coordinates) => coordinates.distance < distance
    );

    const nextLine = this.path.find(
      (coordinates) => coordinates.distance > distance
    );
    if (!nextLine) {
      this.setState({ progress });
      return; // it's the end!
    }
    const lastLine = progress[progress.length - 1];

    const lastLineLatLng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(
      lastLine.lat,
      lastLine.lng
    );

    const nextLineLatLng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(
      nextLine.lat,
      nextLine.lng
    );

    // distance of this line
    const totalDistance = nextLine.distance - lastLine.distance;
    const percentage = (distance - lastLine.distance) / totalDistance;

    const position = window.google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(
      lastLineLatLng,
      nextLineLatLng,
      percentage
    );

    progress = progress.concat(position);
    this.setState({ progress });
  };

  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.path = this.path.map((coordinates, i, array) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        return { ...coordinates, distance: 0 }; // it begins here!
      }
      const { lat: lat1, lng: lng1 } = coordinates;
      const latLong1 = new window.google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng1);

      const { lat: lat2, lng: lng2 } = array[0];
      const latLong2 = new window.google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2);

      // in meters:
      const distance = window.google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
        latLong1,
        latLong2
      );

      return { ...coordinates, distance };
    });

    console.log(this.path);
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={16}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 18.559008, lng: -68.388881 }}
      >
        {this.state.progress && (
          <>
            <Polyline
              path={this.state.progress}
              options={{ strokeColor: "#FF0000 " }}
            />
            <Marker
              position={this.state.progress[this.state.progress.length - 1]}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  };
}

const MapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

export default () => (
  <MapComponent
    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px`, width: "940px" }} />}
    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  />
);
```

Here is sample data from json object, which I get from other component.I need to pass this data using props to the above **path** array.

```
[]
0: {lat: 6.8667528, lng: 79.8769134}
1: {lat: 6.8667112, lng: 79.8769667}
2: {lat: 6.8666556, lng: 79.8769856}
3: {lat: 6.8666023, lng: 79.8769823}
4: {lat: 6.8665584, lng: 79.8770412}
5: {lat: 6.8665478, lng: 79.8771573}
6: {lat: 6.8665295, lng: 79.8772695}
7: {lat: 6.8664823, lng: 79.8774434}
8: {lat: 6.8664434, lng: 79.8777684}
9: {lat: 6.8664023, lng: 79.87823}
10: {lat: 6.8663373, lng: 79.8786712}
11: {lat: 6.86628, lng: 79.87902}
12: {lat: 6.8662312, lng: 79.879335}
13: {lat: 6.8662145, lng: 79.8795562}
14: {lat: 6.8662095, lng: 79.879695}
15: {lat: 6.8661978, lng: 79.8797523}
16: {lat: 6.8659873, lng: 79.8798639}
```

Can anyone help me to build this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/passing-patharray-from-json-then-props-nikzfp?file=Map.js) *`Note: use your own API key for the code to work)`* and a code snippet below on how I implement it. In the `index.js`, I put the path array in json file then imported the json file to be used as an element in my map. Then in my `Map.js`, I set the constuctor(props) and super(props). I put the  `react-google-maps <GoogleMap>` in the `render` inside the `GoogleMapExample` variable. Then I use this variable in the `return`. In the `componentWillMount` function of your code, you need to use `this.props.path.map` to get the value of your path from the props.

Index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { withScriptjs } from "react-google-maps";
import Map from "./Map";
import "./style.css";
import jsonPath from "./data.json";

const App = () => {
  const MapLoader = withScriptjs(Map);

  return (
    <MapLoader
      path={jsonPath}
      googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry,places"
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    />
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Map.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Polyline,
  Marker
} from "react-google-maps";

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      progress: []
    };
  }

  velocity = 5;
  initialDate = new Date();

  getDistance = () => {
    // seconds between when the component loaded and now
    const differentInTime = (new Date() - this.initialDate) / 1000; // pass to seconds
    return differentInTime * this.velocity; // d = v*t -- thanks Newton!
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.interval = window.setInterval(this.moveObject, 1000);
    console.log(this.props.path);
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    window.clearInterval(this.interval);
  };

  moveObject = () => {
    const distance = this.getDistance();
    if (!distance) {
      return;
    }

    let progress = this.path.filter(
      coordinates => coordinates.distance < distance
    );

    const nextLine = this.path.find(
      coordinates => coordinates.distance > distance
    );
    if (!nextLine) {
      this.setState({ progress });
      return; // it's the end!
    }
    const lastLine = progress[progress.length - 1];

    const lastLineLatLng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(
      lastLine.lat,
      lastLine.lng
    );

    const nextLineLatLng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(
      nextLine.lat,
      nextLine.lng
    );

    // distance of this line
    const totalDistance = nextLine.distance - lastLine.distance;
    const percentage = (distance - lastLine.distance) / totalDistance;

    const position = window.google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(
      lastLineLatLng,
      nextLineLatLng,
      percentage
    );

    progress = progress.concat(position);
    this.setState({ progress });
  };

  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.path = this.props.path.map((coordinates, i, array) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        return { ...coordinates, distance: 0 }; // it begins here!
      }
      const { lat: lat1, lng: lng1 } = coordinates;
      const latLong1 = new window.google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng1);

      const { lat: lat2, lng: lng2 } = array[0];
      const latLong2 = new window.google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2);

      // in meters:
      const distance = window.google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
        latLong1,
        latLong2
      );

      return { ...coordinates, distance };
    });

    console.log(this.path);
  };

  render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={16}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 6.8667528, lng: 79.8769134 }}
      >
        {this.state.progress && (
          <>
            <Polyline
              path={this.state.progress}
              options={{ strokeColor: "#FF0000 " }}
            />
            <Marker
              position={this.state.progress[this.state.progress.length - 1]}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "500px" }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```